# Random Actuator change "int_max" via Python

Tags: python, game-engine

so I'm relatively new to Python in BGE (and just Python in general, really.) and I'm trying to make a script that changes the maximum integer on a random actuator. I hovered over it, and it said to type "int_max" but I got an error.

```
    import bge
    from bge import logic as l

    cont = l.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    Dif = own['DIF']
    Timer = (19 - (Dif * 3))
    Rand = cont.actuators['Random']

    if cont.sensors['Always'].positive and Dif != 0:
        Rand.int_max = Timer
    else:
        if Dif == 0:
            Rand.int_max =
```

I have no idea how to change the maximum integer for the actuator, what the attribute is called. Does anyone know how I could change it, or if my script is wrong? And is there any way for me to check what the attribute is named for an actuator/sensor? Thanks a bunch! (If you need more info I'm happy to oblige)

Answer (score 0):

<del>Without knowing the error it's hard to guess, but I think it's caused by a syntax error in the last line. If you don't set a value for `Rand.int_max`, python won't execute this script. To get detailed information about the error, you can open the Blender Console (`Window > Toggle System Console`).</del>

<del>So instead of `Rand.int_max =` write `Rand.int_max = [some integer]`.</del>

**But**, you can't set int_max directly via BGE Python. Instead you have to use a call to `Rand.setIntUniform(lower_bound, upper_bound)`([API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bge.types.SCA_RandomActuator.html#bge.types.SCA_RandomActuator.setIntUniform)). `lower_bound` is *int_min*, `upper_bound` *int_max*.

A few other things you could improve:

- Timers are actually floats, but `Rand.setIntUniform()` requires an Integer, so put the timer value into `int()`.
- Instead of `else: if Dif == 0:` you can write `elif Dif == 0:` (or just `else:` if `Dif` is never negative).
- If you only need the `logic` module and no other bge modules, you can delete the first line, you only need the second line (`from bge import logic as l`).
- Variable names in python are in [*snake_case*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) by convention, so don't call your variables `Dif` or `Rand`, call them `dif` or `rand` instead. But this is a matter of taste, your code is working the same regardless of the naming conventions. The Blender API calls (like `getCurrentController()` are in [*CamelCase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) because Blender is written in C and C++ and these languages use *CamelCase*.
- If you want to activate (= execute) the Random Actuator after setting the value, add `cont.activate(rand)`([API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bge.types.SCA_PythonController.html#bge.types.SCA_PythonController.activate)) to your script. Other than the other Controller types, a Python Controller doesn't execute all connected Actuators by default.

So here is a version of your code that should work:

```
from bge import logic as l

cont = l.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

dif = own['DIF']
timer = int((19 - (dif * 3))) # Convert the result to int
rand = cont.actuators['Random']

if cont.sensors['Always'].positive and dif != 0:
    rand.setIntUniform(0, timer)

# just 'else' if dif can't be negative
elif dif == 0:
    rand.setIntUniform(0, 0)

# If you want to execute the Actuator
cont.activate(rand)
```